# Aurelia with out a router, navigate to login.html and not /#login

Tags: aurelia, identityserver3

I'm writing custom views for Identity Server 3 for its login, logout, consent, etc.  I want to use Aurelia but in Identity server I have to pass in the actual html file.  So, how can I navigate to localhost:9000/login.html and not localhost:9000/#login

Thanks

Comment: So you would like to have Identity Server handle login/logout and everything, but you would like those URLs to be part of an Aurelia application? I'm just trying to make sure I completely understand the question.

Comment: Hey @AshleyGrant, it's Corey from Upper Lake.  Anyway's, to your question no.  These pages are separate from our Aurelia application, it is in its own.  This will be single separate pages to replace the embedded IdSvr's pages.  I can do it with angular, but all of our new stuff is aurelia and I want to keep this the same.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Ashley Grant's help, I was able to create an aurelia replacement for IViewService example coded in angular. [Identity Server 3 IView Service Example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomViewService/CustomViewService/Content)

It's honestly quite easy.  Just create a standard aurelia project and put your html in app.html and view model in app.js.  In addition to having the vendor_bundle reference link in your Index.html you will also have to create a link for the app_bundle as well because of a bug that tries to locate app_bundle in the root of your folder structure for Identity Server.

If anyone is interested in the source I can put something together just IM me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the # from URLs in an aurelia application:

[Configuring PushState](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7)

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Aurelia is "just JavaScript," so when you want to link to another page on your site, you'll do it the same way you always would, by giving either an absolute or relative path to the file. You're not going to be able to link to an HTML file that is in your bundle though, the file will have to be unbundled, like `index.html` is.

At this point, this becomes just a standard JavaScript question about building a URL, and not anything to do with Aurelia. So just have the url point to wherever `login.html` is. I'm hoping this is enough for the answer, if not we can discuss it further.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ashley Grant. Ya I know its simple but after our traning with you I've been strickly in C# mode. I have some catching up to do. If you could expand on your response with an example I would appreciate it. How do I unbundle?

Comment: You just keep the file outside the src folder. Just like index.html file is unbundled.

Comment: @chdev77 A simple `window.location = '/login.html';` should work

Comment: @AshleyGrant what about the view model?  I've moved them out of the src.  The pages loads the view model doesn't.

Comment: @Fabio Luz this does not load the view model login.js

Comment: I'm drowning here fellas...anyone got a clue?

Comment: @chdev77 you said you only want to load login.html, that tells me there isn't a viewmodel. I'm pretty sure Fabio and I aren't fully understanding the question at this point.

Comment: for what it's worth, I sent a tweet to Brock Allen to see if he can help ya

Comment: @Ashley Gran This is an Aurelia question.  How can I use Aurelia based html page and view model outside of the src/ app bundle, etc.  I suppose I can't.  I want to navigate to localhost:9000/login.html and have it load the aurelia framework, etc.  That is why I titled it Aurelia...sorry but thought that would get it.  I want all the binding, injection to work, etc...

Comment: Brock responded with this: https://twitter.com/BrockLAllen/status/846459418862653442

Comment: I don't know how else to ask.  Oh well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139185/discussion-between-ashley-grant-and-chdev77).